# как найти максимальное значение в ArraList используя лямбда выражение без stream?

Tags: java, lambda

Есть ИНТЕРФЕЙС

```
interface BestStudent{
    Student theBest(ArrayList<Student> students);
}
```

Class Student с Getter setter

```
public class Student{
    String fullName;
    int age;
    double gpa;
    int height;
    public Student(String fullName, int age, double gpa, int height) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.age = age;
        this.gpa = gpa;
        this.height = height;
    }
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public double getGpa() {
        return gpa;
    }

    public void setGpa(double gpa) {
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

Class StudentsAwards

```
class StudentAwards{
    Student theMostGPA(ArrayList<Student> students){
        BestStudent bestStudent=(ArrayList<Student> students1) -> {
            double max = students.get(0).getGpa();

            return students1.;
        };
        return bestStudent.theBest(students);
    }
```

В классе StudentAwards написал метод `Student theMostGPA(ArrayList<Student> students)` то есть он выводит студента из списка у кого самый высокий GPA. Как написать условие?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [`Collections::max(Collection<? extends T> coll, Comparator<? super T> comp)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-), который для пустой коллекции выбросит `NoSuchElementException`.

Тогда можно будет сразу в интерфейсе `BestStudent` написать статическую реализацию с использованием компаратора `Comparator.comparingDouble`, и/или добавить метод с компаратором в виде аргумента

```java
interface BestStudent {
    static Student theBest(List<Student> students) {
        return theBest(students, Comparator.comparingDouble(Student::getGpa));
    }

    static Student theBest(List<Student> students, Comparator<Student> cmp) {
        return Collections.max(students, cmp);
    }
}
```

и вызывать её соответственно так:

```java
class StudentAwards {
    Student theMostGPA(List<Student> students) {
        return BestStudent.theBest(students);
    }
}
```

---

Для использования с лямбдой код может выглядеть так:

```java
interface BestStudent {
    Student theBest(List<Student> students);
}

class StudentAwards {
    Student theMostGPA(List<Student> students) {
        BestStudent bs = studs -> Collections.max(studs, Comparator.comparingDouble(Student::getGpa));
        return bs.theBest(students);
    }
}
```

---

Также следует использовать интерфейс `List` вместо конкретной реализации `ArrayList` в качестве аргументов методов, и для корректного представления экземпляров `Student` нужно переопределить метод `toString`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
Student theMostGPA(ArrayList<Student> students) {
    if (students.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    List<Student> copy = new ArrayList<>(students);
    copy.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(Student::getGpa).reversed());
    return copy.get(0);
}
```

Я правда не очень понимаю, зачем вам интерфейс BestStudent

Comment: Поиск максимума проще/продуктивнее (O(N)), чем сортировка всего массива (O(N log N)) и возврат первого/последнего элемента